# React createContext and useReducer undefined value error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a React typescript project that I'm working on and am having some issues with the context API.

I've tried passing different types to the `createContext` method and those all are working as expected. However, when I try using the `useReducer` hook I get the following error:

```
Syntax error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (0:undefined)
```

I have passed the default value in as empty objects like this (I have a feeling this is where I am getting the error but this method has worked for me previously):

```
const AppContext: Context<[AppContextSchema, Dispatch<DispatchReturn>]> = createContext<[AppContextSchema, Dispatch<DispatchReturn>]>([
    {} as AppContextSchema,
    {} as Dispatch<DispatchReturn>
]);
```

I have a method to initialize the `AppContextSchema` object in the provider:

```
export const InitializeContext = (): AppContextSchema => {
    return {
        user: {
            ...
        },
    };
}
```

Here is the reducer that I have implemented that is passed to the `useReducer` hook:

```
export type DispatchReturn = {
    [key: string]: User | string;
    type: string;
}

export const AppContextReducer = (state: AppContextSchema, payload: DispatchReturn): AppContextSchema => {
    switch (payload.type) {
        case UPDATE_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: { ...(payload.user as User) }
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And finally here is where I am passing the value to the `AppContext.Provider`:

```
function App() {
return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={useReducer(AppContextReducer, InitializeContext())}>
        <div className="App">
            ...
        </div>
    </AppContext.Provider>
 );
}
```

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciate. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If I set the context type to `any` as seen here: `const AppContext: Context<any> = createContext([{} as AppContextSchema, {} as Dispatch<DispatchReturn>]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is an issue with either Typescript, @typscript-eslint/eslint-plugin or @typescript-eslint/parser or a combination of the three being used together.

The issue actually existed when defining the `Context` type. `Context` is a generic object that expects a tuple as the argument. For whatever reason when giving a tuple as the argument passed to the `Context` object it was throwing the error described above. Here is the code that was causing the error:

```
const AppContext: Context<[AppContextSchema, Dispatch<DispatchReturn>]> = ...
```

In order to fix this issue I downgraded my Typescript version to 3.9.7.

To fix this I ran the following commands:

1. `npm uninstall typescript` or `yarn remove typescript`
2. `npm install typescript@3.9.7` or `yarn add typescript@3.9.7`
3. `rm package.lock` or `rm yarn.lock`
4. `rm -rf node_modules`
5. `npm install` or `yarn install`

Hopefully this saves someone from the same headache that it gave me.